# How to add listener to each checkboxes of a checkboxgroup in extjs

Tags: extjs

How to add listener for check or uncheck a checkbox from a checkboxgroup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `change : ( Ext.form.CheckboxGroup this, Array checked )` event like so:

```
var checkboxgrp = new Ext.form.CheckBoxGroup({
.. config..
listeners : {
  change : {
    fn : function(checkbox, checked){
      //your logic
    },
    scope : your-scope //---> Optional
  }
}
```

This works for both Ext 2 and 3 versions. Don't know about 1 and 4.